# Triangle fit to square

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i am new to adobe illustrator and tried to fit an triangle to a square. The problem is that that is not fitting perfectly. Either the corner are outside or the line is not ending with the square. Is there a way to match them perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Even if your stroked shapes are perfectly aligned, the corners will extrude and you won't get a perfect fit.

Changing the *Align Stroke* attribute won't help.

[image]

In the following I'll show two different solutions to the problem. There might be more.

### Use Round Join

If you can live with the appearance, the easiest solution by far is to simply set the *Corner* attribute to *Round Join*. That way all corners are circular and will always fit.

[image]

### Remake the shape

If you need sharp corners, you can remake your graphics so the outer shape is one closed path and the inner lines are separate paths.

In this case I would cut the horizontal line of the triangle, delete the lower horizontal line of the rectangle, join the two shapes the two places where they meet and then paste the horizontal line in place.

[image]

Comment: Wow! I think I should remove my answer! My approach is wrong?

Comment: :'( I cant make such cute animation! :@ Everything cute belongs to stupid photoshop.

Comment: @RussianBlue, everything you say in your answer is true, but I think the OP's problem is how the corners overlap in an ugly way. If you zoom in on your drawing you should see the same problem.

Comment: I learn from your answer too. Thank you.

Comment: @RussianBlue, you can make cut animations too! I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) for PC. I must admit I often spend ridiculously long time finding the right crop and positioning everything just right. I also sometimes need to rehearse a few times so the animation doesn't get too confusing to watch. It helps me notice how messy I do some stuff. 

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, unify the lines into a single shape, not just move lines next to each other.

Comment: @Wolff Thank you so much . I will use that for making animation.

Comment: @Wolff thats why I dont record videos instead i animate them. So what i do is following: I move the mouse to next frame position, capture an image, move to next capture. then i assemble it afterwards. It helps that i have a footpedal for image capture to disk. Thisway its not a problem that i am pushing keys for other reasons. This is way faster than screecapturing with a few rehersals and produces better results with less mistakes and with less data bandwdith.

Answer (score 2):

Basic math! The triangle’s edge length needs to be same as one of the square’s/rectangle’s sides.

Draw them with equal length.

The go to outline mode (Ctrl+y). Place them manually over each other. hit (ctrl+y) again to go back into normal mode.

Make sure Smart guide is on, so that they will snap perfectly. Also centrally align them.
[image]

[image]