# Remove small things from pen tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

Sorry for not being able to phrase it correctly, but I drew a cube, and there are some parts overriding some lines and I was wondering how to remove/delete them?

Here is a picture to better describe it:

[image]

Comment: I answered a very similar question a couple of hours ago: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/158420

Comment: Sweet! I'll take a look at it. Thank you, @Wolff!

Comment: Oops, there is an issue... I don't have all those settings for some reason

Comment: I just have the following, @Wolff : https://imgur.com/a/TbhWnU1

Comment: Daniel, from the little hamburger menu ON the Stroke panel.. choose "Show Options".

Comment: Ohhhhhh, thank you so much, @Scott!!

Comment: Or just click the little icon left of "Stroke": https://i.imgur.com/AbvZHFy.gif

Comment: ..yeah `:)` or that...